# Need an R function to remove numbers in a list that are greater than the previous number

Tags: r, function, loops

I would like to find numbers greater than the previous number by 5 and remove them.

For example, starting with the list below:

```
list <- c(1,1,15,1,4,2,3,1,20,1,3,2)
```

Resulting in the list below:

```
list <- c(1,1,1,4,2,3,1,1,3,2)
```

This removed 15 and 20 from the original list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `diff` :

```
list[c(TRUE, diff(list) <= 5)]
#[1] 1 1 1 4 2 3 1 1 3 2
```

Other options could be :

```
list[c(TRUE, tail(list, -1) - head(list, -1) <= 5)]
list[list - dplyr::lag(list, default = list[1]) <= 5]
list[list - data.table::shift(list, fill = list[1]) <= 5]
```

---

Instead of removing if we want to replace them with mean of corresponding values, we can turn the values to `NA` and then use `na.approx`.

```
list[c(FALSE, diff(list) >= 5)] <- NA
zoo::na.approx(list)
#[1] 1 1 1 1 4 2 3 1 1 1 3 2
```

Comment: Thanks, Ronak! What if instead of removing the number, I wanted to replace the number with the average of the previous and following numbers? For example, 15 would become 1 (the average of 1 and 1).

Comment: Much appreciated, @Ronak Shah!

Answer (score 1):

using base

```
x <- c(1,1,15,1,4,2,3,1,20,1,3,2)
x[which(diff(c(0,x)) < 5 | diff(c(0, x)) < 0)]
#[1] 1 1 1 4 2 3 1 1 3 2
```